# Pino-pretty customPrettifiers doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, pino

I want to contomize the time output in terminal with `customPrettifiers` but it gives me error

```js
import pino from "pino"

const logger = pino({
    transport: {
        targets: [
            { target: "pino-pretty", options: { destination: "./logs.log", mkdir: true, colorize: false } },
            {
                target: "pino-pretty",
                options: {
                    destination: process.stdout.fd,
                    customPrettifiers: {
                        time: (timestamp) => `Time: ${timestamp}`,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
})

logger.info("hi")
```

gives me error :

```
node:internal/per_context/domexception:53
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(this);
    ^
DOMException [DataCloneError]: (timestamp) => `Time: ${timestamp}` could not be cloned.
    at new DOMException (node:internal/per_context/domexception:53:5)
    at new Worker (node:internal/worker:266:17)
```

Comment: Think has to do with the fact that since ~2021 and version 7, Pino, while building the transport, spins up a separate "Worker" which has a completely separate context and thus can only serialize basic JSON data and not functions in/out of it. https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty#handling-non-serializable-options is likely to help if you're using pure JavaScript, but somebody smarter than me needs to figure out how to get this to work with TypeScript, given Pino (in transport.js) is using Node module createRequire and resolve internally, which doesn't seem to play well.